# Issue running MxBuild on Debian : ERROR: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Mendix.Modeler.Utility.AssemblyResolver'

Tags: c#, mono, debian, mendix

Using **MxBuild** for creating the deployment package(.mda file) for Mendix app

Command executed :

```
mono modeler/mxbuild.exe --output="Automation" --java-home =/usr/lib/jvm --java-exe-path=/usr/lib/jvm/bin/java Automation.mpr
```

Error I am getting :

ERROR: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Mendix.Modeler.Utility.AssemblyResolver' from assembly 'Mendix.Modeler.Utility, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. at Mendix.CommandLine.Shared.ProgramHelper.InitializeAndRun[T] (System.Func`2[T,TResult] program, System.Reflection.Assembly[] extraAssemblies) [0x00000] in <009e4959434f43ae9753a7ededb54a25>:0

I am referring the directions mentioned [here](https://docs.mendix.com/refguide/mxbuild).

As mentioned in this documentation, we can use MxBuild on Windows as well as Linux. If I use Windows here, no issue is occurring.

**Mono version 4.6** is used here as I have to use mxbuild.exe on debian.(Suggested in documentation)

Is this something related to Mono or Mendix ?

Comment: where did you place the `Mendix.Modeler.Utility.dll` file?

Answer (score 0):

Ran into similar issues on CentOS and got the answer from the #mendix support to try this variant of the mendix docker buildpack:
https://github.com/MXClyde/docker-mendix-buildpack/tree/telegrafext-nonroot

[Edit 2019-08-23]
We did try check the solution out and ran into another error still related to permission issues. 
We are going to relate this back to mendix support and follow up here.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your contribution. If you haven't tested your answer, consider posting it as a comment. Answers have the assumption attached that they have been tested, and should be working to the best knowledge of the person posting the answer.

Comment: @tituszban Thank your for pointing this out to me. I am going to adhere to your advise for the future. I have tried to post my statement as a comment and got the response from the system that I would need 50 points in reputation to add a comment. Therefore please accept that I would leave this here as an answer.